# Find and replace string in files recursively, create backup for affected files

Tags: bash, unix, replace, cygwin, backup

I want to find and replace the string "foo" with "bra" in several files, traversing through directories (Linux machine). If a string is replaced in file "example.txt" I need that file to be copied to "example.text.old" before string replacement.

I can replace the string is files recursively like this:

```
find . -type f -name '*' -exec sed -i  's/test1/test2/g' {} +
```

and it works fine, but no backup for when something doesnt work.

Alternatively, I have stumbled upon this perl script that works, albeit I am more comfortable using native unix commands.

```
# perl -e "s/old_string/new_string/g;" -pi.save $(find DirectoryName -type f)
```

This, however, this backs up **ALL** files, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I made this bash script **replace.sh** to make it easy for later reuse

```
#!/bin/bash
old=$1
new=$2
grep -r -l "$old" --exclude='*.{sh,old}' * | while read -r line ; do
  cp "$line" "$line.old"
  echo "Replacing '$old' with '$new' in file '$line'"
  sed -i "s/$old/$new/g" "$
done
```

make it executable

```
$chmod +x replace.sh
```

**Note: if using Cygwin for Windows** you may need to use dos2unix: `dos2unix replace.sh`

Then run it with two strings as arguments, the string to find and the one that will replace is

```
./replace.sh foo bar
```

This makes a backup (*.old*) of all files (excluding .*old* and *.sh*) containing the word 'foo', then replaces it with 'bar'

Any useful tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: it should be noted that this script runs from the directory it is placed in and all subdirectories

Comment: similar question on unix stackexchange: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/295696/109046